# Javascript проверить видимость элемента

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня!

Прошу помощи. Как проверить видимость элемента в моем случае?

```js
var strings = document.getElementsByClassName('hidstr');

for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i += 1) {
 if ( strings[i].offsetHeight > 0 ) {
  // действие
 }
}
```

проблема в том что offsetHeight всегда равно нулю не только у невидимых элементов, но иногда и у тех, которые явно видны на странице.
Не ищу даже объяснения, почему так (страница полностью валидна), сколько ищу другой вариант как определить, видим элемент или нет.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: а при каких случаях `offsetHeight = 0`, но элемент виден. Когда такое бывает?

Comment: Вы хотите запускать какое-то действие над элементом, после того как до скролите к нему? Например анимацию?

Comment: @ThisMan, сам удивлен таким положением дел. Логика такая - на странице блоки <div>. В них - элемент textarea с классом hidstr. Пользователь может скрывать ненужные блоки div (делать им display:none;). Затем при обработке данных со страницы, обрабатываются только видимые блоки, т.е. берутся в работу только те, у которых textarea class="hidstr" и offsetHeight=0. На практике получается так, что некоторые элементы, не будучи скрытыми, почему то выдают offsetHeight=0 и не попадают в обработку